# Output second column from database

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to get back or read out all the data from a column from a database so that I can check whether, for example, the E-Mail column contains a specific e-mail.

If I run the code like this, I get the first email address back correctly, but not the second.

With WHERE I would get it right, but then I had to look for the ID number and adapt the code every time.

How can I output the second column?

```py
    from operator import index
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
    from userpasswort.xy import Ui_MainWindow
    from userpasswort.bu.oo import Ui_alper
    from PySide6 import QtSql
    class fm(QMainWindow, Ui_alper):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.newaccount.clicked.connect(self.weiter)
    def weiter(self):
    main.show()
    class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.offene = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
    self.offene.setTable('info')
    self.continue_2.clicked.connect(self.datenbank)

    def datenbank(self):
    model = self.offene
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec( "SELECT email FROM info ")
    query.first()
    print(query.value(0)) **#here i get the correct email adress**
    print(query.value(1)) **#here i get NON**E
    model.select()
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('userpasswort.sqlite')
    app = QApplication()
    main = Main()
    mf= fm()
    mf.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and enclose your code in [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/code-blocks/).  Also make sure your code is correctly indented.

Answer (score 0):

As documented, [query.first()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlQuery.html#PySide2.QtSql.PySide2.QtSql.QSqlQuery.first) gives you the first result. Hence, no other result will be part of this response.

I would suggest replacing query.first() with [query.next()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlQuery.html#PySide2.QtSql.PySide2.QtSql.QSqlQuery.next) in a while loop:

```
addresses = []
while query.next():
    addresses.append(query.value(0))
```